# The connection between the Collatz Conjecture and the Optic Equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, collatz-conjecture

The Collatz Conjecture is fun for those of us who have never taken mathematics in university in any meaningful way.  It's also probably fun for all of you who have gone to university.

So I want to ask about some basic relationships about the Collatz Conjecture.

For some reason $3n+1$ and $n+1$ work on the odd edge and no others.  It's easy to figure out why these do not ever run into infinity unless you start from infinity.

Generalised, given n(k+1) → if odd: $a × n(k) + b$; if even: $n/c$,

It's also easy to figure out that in $mod(ac)$ that each modular instance excluded from $mod(a)$ and $mod(c)$ should point directly towards a power of 2.  In $n+1$, 1 → 2.  In $3n+1$, 1 → 4 and 5 → 16.  Any subsequent odd will be found as members of these excluded modular instances.

Now the funny thing about these two is the odd edges.  If you take out the even edge, the instance $n+1$ will have a converging ratio of $\phi$ (Golden Ratio) between any $k$ and $k+1$.  The instance $3n+1$ will have a converging ratio of $\phi(3)$ (Bronze Ratio).

Now I know that Bronze Ratio is related to the Heptagon (the longest diagonal divided by the shortest edge will equal $\phi(3)$.  And there is a whole bunch of exciting stuff in this article that is a bit above my head. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heptagonal_triangle

The satisfaction of the cubic mentioned in the article looks interesting (although it might be uninteresting, I have no idea.)

Now, my math is not at all advanced enough to cement the connection here.  As I said, I didn't take math beyond high school (Financial math is not enough. *sigh*.)  But my spider senses are tingling here.  Is anyone else's spider senses tingling?

Edit: I have edited this question to be as clear as I can muster.  I had an error in which identity I was drawing attention to but have corrected that (I hope.)  What I am looking for is whether $\phi$ and $\phi(3)$ are of especial interest in the Collatz conjecture.

Comment: (1) which "optic equation" are you talking about (2) which "edges" are you talking about

Comment: @Kartik, the two-ladder problem.  Beyond that I am guessing.  My first guess is the short edge is n(k), the long edge is n(k+1).  Perhaps the gap between the two edges is also n(k+1).  Not entirely sure.  As for the previous edges mentioned towards the top, that refers to the side of the steps.

Comment: Please make your question clearer . . Include all neccecary context. Its not making any sense to me now.

Comment: Give me a monent so I can make it clearer in my head.

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure if I am making anything clearer.  And I don't know how to make myself clearer.  *eek*  Edit: now that I think about it, thank you for pointing out that the two-ladder is not what I wanted.

Comment: "It's easy to figure out why these do not ever run into infinity unless you start from infinity." - You do not seem to understand mathematical concepts very well.

Comment: True, I never did go to university.  There is nothing formal about that statement.  But I still stand by that statement.

Comment: After a year without clarification what is the "optic equation" I think this is only a buzz word for the bullet line. (-1) now...

Answer (score 1):

Well, I gave it a whirl.  The result is surprising.

The harmonic mean of $n$ and$\phi_3$ seems to be the experimentally obtained number of "somewhere around $\frac{3}{4}$."  Or that was how it was described on Wikipedia.

That is:

$$\frac{Decay}{Step}=\frac{\phi_3}{1+\phi_3}\approx0.767...$$

I predict in a non-canonic fashion that for any a and b, we can obtain a Pisot number, $\phi_{a,b}$ to derive a decay rate per step.

$$\kappa_{a,b}=\frac{\phi_{a,b}}{1+\phi_{a,b}}$$

Where:

$$\phi_{a,b}=\frac{a\pm\sqrt{a^2+4b}}{2}$$

However, this does not translate to heptagonal triangles under any elementary euclidean measure.  I can't say if anything is revealed in hyperbolic geometry because I have no way of working with that stuff yet.